# Does the Chromium Bluetooth Cordova plugin work on the Cordova web view?

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, chromium

I know that someone wrapped the Chromium Bluetooth API into a [Cordova plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.bluetooth), but I'm wondering how this works.  On the dev page it says for Chromium devices - will this work for only specific devices running Cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Cordova plugin implements the chrome.bluetooth API in iOS/Android native code.

That is to say that it reproduces the functionality provided in Chromium so that you can use it in your Cordova application.

The only restrictions on which devices it supports should be the required version of iOS or Android the port specifies - for example it seems like the Android version requires API level 14 (Android 4.0), and the minimum version of Cordova specified (3.0)